# Bayesian analysis in R: Probability of default, low default portfolios

Tags: risk, risk-management, credit-risk, bayes-theory

I want to apply the knowledge of this [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.5550) (Bayesian estimation of probabilities of default for low default portfolios, by Dirk Tasche) in R, but I can't find the right bayesian package and functions to use. Can you help me?

Comment: Your link is not working.#

Comment: There are a number of Bayesian packages in R. My favorite is Stan. But you'll need to know what you're doing.

Comment: That's the problem, maybe. I'm not able to understand how to apply such things on R, from the part about one observation period and correlated defaults on. I think there are formulas that cannot be applied directly with a specific function, am I right?